# How to store the logged in user activity or data in wpf

Tags: sql-server, wpf

In my WPf application I have a page  which has text boxes to input values related to dimensions, speed  etc. and this is saved in a file and Iam using Xml serialier function to save it locally  . I have a file browser from which I can access these files through the names given to them when they were saved.
  I am using SQL Server database for saving all the credentials  for registration and Log In. So,now if a user logs in , with the file browser which gets all the file saved locally . How can he just get to see only the files that he created and saved but not of other user ( till the time he is logged in) . when user2 (other user) logs in user2 just get to see his own files not of user1 .
 Note:( Files are saved locally and Login credentials are saved in Sql server )

P.S : This is the first time iam asking something online .I don't know how to start . I need an idea how should I start.

Comment: @Chris mark   while saving the details how would I know that these files were made by user1 while he was  log in and now only his files will be shown among all the saved files. As iam saving everything in the xml not in the database  .How would I identify that these files were made and saved by user1 not user2 ... or some user3 . Because there could be many users logging in and making files. How to track them based on log in and how to retreive them based on login

Answer (score 0):

I would return the results via a stored procedure that accepts a Boolean parameter specifying whether or not the user is logged in.

Your query might have a WHERE clause something along the lines of:

```
WHERE
    @UserIsLoggedIn = 1
    OR UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: while saving the details how would I know that these files were made by user1 while he was log in and now only his files will be shown among all the saved files. As iam saving everything in the xml not in the database .How would I identify that these files were made and saved by user1 not user2 ... or some user3 . Because there could be many users logging in and making files. How to track them based on log in and how to retreive them based on login

Comment: Could you record the user's ID in a xml attribute, and then use this to only pull back the relevant files?